# How can I create a jQuery Show/Hide password function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a Show/Hide button for password inputs within my form. Everything works as it should, except that I don't really know how to translate this into a function to apply it to any password input on the fly. The main issue is that I have to not append any element from within the function as the extra text input and label are used by another plugin to detect the strength of the password when typed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 "use strict"; // Start of use strict

 if ($(window).width() < 700){

  $('.password-button-main').on('click', function() {
   $("#pass-on").hide();
   $("#pass-off").show();
   $('.password-button-main > i').removeClass('fa-eye-slash');
   $('.password-button-main > i').addClass('fa-eye');
   setTimeout(function(){
    $("#pass-on").show();
    $("#pass-off").hide();
    $('.password-button-main > i').addClass('fa-eye-slash');
    $('.password-button-main > i').removeClass('fa-eye');
   }, 800);
  });


  $('.password-button-verify').on('click', function() {
   $("#pass-verify-on").hide();
   $("#pass-verify-off").show();
   $('.password-button-verify > i').removeClass('fa-eye-slash');
   $('.password-button-verify > i').addClass('fa-eye');
   setTimeout(function(){
    $("#pass-verify-on").show();
    $("#pass-verify-off").hide();
    $('.password-button-verify > i').addClass('fa-eye-slash');
    $('.password-button-verify > i').removeClass('fa-eye');
   }, 800);
  });

 } else {

  $('.password-button-main').on('mousedown', function() {
    $("#pass-on").hide();
    $("#pass-off").show();
    $('.password-button-main > i').removeClass('fa-eye-slash');
    $('.password-button-main > i').addClass('fa-eye');
  });

  $('.password-button-main').on('mouseup', function() {
    $("#pass-on").show();
    $("#pass-off").hide();
    $('.password-button-main > i').addClass('fa-eye-slash');
    $('.password-button-main > i').removeClass('fa-eye');
  });

  $('.password-button-main').on('mouseout', function() {
    $("#pass-on").show();
    $("#pass-off").hide();
    $('.password-button-main > i').addClass('fa-eye-slash');
    $('.password-button-main > i').removeClass('fa-eye');
  });


  $('.password-button-verify').on('mousedown', function() {
    $("#pass-verify-on").hide();
    $("#pass-verify-off").show();
    $('.password-button-verify > i').removeClass('fa-eye-slash');
    $('.password-button-verify > i').addClass('fa-eye');
  });

  $('.password-button-verify').on('mouseup', function() {
    $("#pass-verify-on").show();
    $("#pass-verify-off").hide();
    $('.password-button-verify > i').addClass('fa-eye-slash');
    $('.password-button-verify > i').removeClass('fa-eye');
  });

  $('.password-button-verify').on('mouseout', function() {
    $("#pass-verify-on").show();
    $("#pas-verifys-off").hide();
    $('.password-button-verify > i').addClass('fa-eye-slash');
    $('.password-button-verify > i').removeClass('fa-eye');
  });

 }

 $('#pass-on').on('focus', function(){
  $('#pass-on').keyup(function() {
   $('#pass-off').val($(this).val());
  });
 });

 $('#pass-off').on('focus', function(){
  $('#pass-off').keyup(function() {
   $('#pass-on').val($(this).val());
  });
 });


 $('#pass-verify-on').on('focus', function(){
  $('#pass-verify-on').keyup(function() {
   $('#pass-verify-off').val($(this).val());
  });
 });

 $('#pass-verify-off').on('focus', function(){
  $('#pass-verify-off').keyup(function() {
   $('#pass-verify-on').val($(this).val());
  });
 });

}); // End of use strict
```

```css
/*
 * Form input styling
 */

  .form-group {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
 }

 .form-layout input[type="text"],
 .form-layout input[type="password"],
 .form-layout input[type="email"] {
 /* font-size: 1.7rem;
 height: 2.8rem; */
  /* width: 100%; */
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 2.8rem;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  border-radius: 0;
 }

 ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
     opacity: 0 !important;
    }

    :-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
     opacity: 0 !important;
    }

    ::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
     opacity: 0 !important;
    }

    :-ms-input-placeholder {
     opacity: 0 !important;
    }

 .form-layout label {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 2.5rem;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  color: #6c757d;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: .5s;
 }

 .form-layout input:focus,
 .form-layout input:valid {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #03a9f4;
 }

 .form-layout input:focus ~ label,
 .form-layout input:valid ~ label {
  top: -1.5rem;
  left: 0;
  color: #03a9f4;
  font-size: .8rem;
 }

/*
 * Form password strength bar
 */

 .jquery-result-1 {
  border-radius: 0;
 }

/*
 * Form button styling
 */

 .btn-form {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #47a447;
  border:none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
  outline: none !important;
  cursor: pointer !important;
 }

 .btn-green {
  background-color: #47a447;
 }

 .btn-orange {
  background-color: #f4511e;
 }

 .btn-green:hover {
  background-color: #67b647;
 }

 .btn-orange:hover {
  background-color: #f0353c;
 }

 .btn-text {
  margin-left: 5px;
 }

/*
 * Password show/hide button
 */

 .password-button {
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
 }

 .password-button i {
  padding: 14px 19px;
  color: darkgray;
 }

 .password-button:hover > i {
  color: #3a3a3a;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="form-layout" method="post" id="login-form">

   <h2 class="form-layout-heading"><i class="far fa-user-circle"></i></h2>

    <div class="form-group">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt_uname" placeholder="Enter Username" autocomplete="off" value="" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('<?php echo $user->username_error; ?>')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required />
     <label>Username</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt_umail" placeholder="Enter E-Mail" autocomplete="off" value="" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('<?php echo $user->email_error; ?>')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required />
     <label>E-mail</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group input-group">
       <input type="password" id="pass-on" title="<?php echo $user->valid_password_error; ?>" class="form-control" name="txt_upass" placeholder="Enter Password" autocomplete="off" value="" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('<?php echo $user->password_error; ?>')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required />
       <input type="text" id="pass-off" title="<?php echo $user->valid_password_error; ?>" class="form-control" style="display: none;" placeholder="Enter Password" autocomplete="off" value="" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('<?php echo $user->password_error; ?>')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required />
     <label>Password</label>
     <div class="input-group-append">
         <span class="password-button password-button-main"><i class="fas fa-eye-slash"></i></span>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group progress jquery-result-1" style="height: 10px;">
     <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%;"></div>
    </div>
        
     <div class="form-group input-group">
      <input type="password" id="pass-verify-on" title="<?php echo $user->valid_password_error; ?>" class="form-control" name="txt_upass_ok" placeholder="Retype Password" autocomplete="off" value="" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('<?php echo $user->password_error; ?>')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required />
      <input type="text" id="pass-verify-off" title="<?php echo $user->valid_password_error; ?>" class="form-control" style="display: none;" placeholder="Retype Password" autocomplete="off" value="" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('<?php echo $user->password_error; ?>')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required />
      <label>Retype Password</label>
      <div class="input-group-append">
          <span class="password-button password-button-verify"><i class="fas fa-eye-slash"></i></span>
        </div>
     </div>


    <button type="submit" name="btn-signup" class="btn-form btn-green">
     <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
     <span class="btn-text">Sign Up</span>
    </button>

  </form>
```

Comment: I think your question is not entirely clear but if you wanted to hide/ show a password then you could maybe try using just 1 password input and on click you could changed the type of the input from password to text hence showing the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to have two different inputs and show/hide them - just toggle the `type` of the password input between `password` and `text`.

*(really quick contrived example)*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let $pw = $('#password')
  let $t = $('#toggle')
  
  function setOriginalState() {
    $pw.attr('type', 'password')
    $t.text('Show')
  }

  $t.on('click', () => {
    const isPw = $pw.attr('type') === 'password'
    
    if (isPw) {
      $pw.attr('type', 'text')
      $t.text('Hide')
      
      setTimeout(setOriginalState, 800)
    } else {
      setOriginalState()
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="password" id="password">
<button id="toggle">Show</button>
```

---

**Update** To ensure multiple password inputs can be toggled, you need to adjust the logic a bit. Here's one way using custom data properties (`[data-id]`) on each button to reference the correct input.

```js
function togglePasswordVisibility($pw, on) {
  $pw.attr('type', on ? 'password' : 'text');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-id]').on('click', function() {
    const $this = $(this);
    const id = $this.data('id')
    const $pw = $(`#${id}`);

    togglePasswordVisibility($pw, false);
    $this.prop('disabled', true);

    setTimeout(function() {
      togglePasswordVisibility($pw, true);
      $this.prop('disabled', false);
    }, 800);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="group">
  <input type="password" id="password1">
  <button data-id="password1">Show</button>
</div>

<div class="group">
  <input type="password" id="password2">
  <button data-id="password2">Show</button>
</div>

<div class="group">
  <input type="password" id="password3">
  <button data-id="password3">Show</button>
</div>
```

Final Update:

```
    function togglePasswordVisibility($pw, on, $eye) {
    $pw.attr('type', on ? 'password' : 'text');
    $eye.toggleClass('fa-eye-slash fa-eye');
}

$("[type=password]").each(function () {
    var $pw = $(this);
    var $eye = $("<i>").addClass("fas fa-eye-slash").click(function () {
        togglePasswordVisibility($pw, false, $eye);
        setTimeout(function() {
            togglePasswordVisibility($pw, true, $eye);
        }, 800);
    });
    $pw.parent().append(
        $("<div>").addClass("input-group-append").append(
            $("<span>").addClass("password-button password-button-main").append($eye)
        )
    );
});
```

Comment: Super good advice. But how can I enhance this even more, in the sense that if I have 3 password text fields, it would be counterproductive to have each of them set up with a distinct id. How could I give it a custom attribute (such as show-password="on") and apply a global function to all of them when I click their associated buttons individually and reveal their password individually.

Comment: You'll need to identify each password field uniquely, so it's not counterproductive to keep an `id`. I'll update the answer, but essentially you just need to factor out the logic to toggle the type based upon the id (and the buttons will need to have a reference to the correct input).

Comment: I would like something like this: github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-show-password where the function is controlled via a standard parameter: <input id="password" class="form-control" type="password" data-toggle="password">

Comment: Yup, I guess I can't get it any better than this. Thank you and you are awesome! :)

Comment: This is usually what I settle with if I don't have any frameworks available to me to manage the data-binding and interfacing between components. Glad it'll help!

Comment: `function togglePasswordVisibility($pw, on, $eye) {
$pw.attr('type', on ? 'password' : 'text');
$eye.toggleClass('fa-eye-slash fa-eye');
}

$("[type=password]").each(function () {
var $pw = $(this);
var $eye = $("<i>").addClass("fas fa-eye-slash").click(function () {
togglePasswordVisibility($pw, false, $eye);
setTimeout(function() {
togglePasswordVisibility($pw, true, $eye);
}, 800);
});
$pw.parent().append(
$("<div>").addClass("input-group-append").append(
$("<span>").addClass("password-button password-button-main").append($eye)
)
);
});`

Comment: This is the final version of the code. Now it will apply to any password input with no ID restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div class="label-input">
  <i class="icon eye js_show_password visibility"></i>
  <input class="input error" id="password-input" type="password" value="12345678">
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).on('click','.js_show_password',function(){
if ($('#password-input').attr('type') == 'password'){
  $(this).removeClass('visibility').addClass('visibility_off');
  $('#password-input').attr('type', 'text');
} else {
  $(this).removeClass('visibility_off').addClass('visibility');
  $('#password-input').attr('type', 'password');
}
return false;
```

});

Answer (score 0):

To create a function in JavasScript, you can:

```
function someName(someVariable) {
  // Copy and paste your code here!
}
```

For your example, this could be a combination of an onclick event in your HTML and the function in your JS:

```
<button onclick="toggleField(true, 'old')">Click me</button>
```

Whenever someone clicks on **Click me**, the function `toggleField` is called. In your JS:

```
function toggleField(bool, type) {
  if (bool === true && type === 'old') {
    $(this).show();
  } else {
    $(this).hide();
  }   
}
```

Comment: But how can I make 3 fields who are of type password show their values in text form individually when their buttons are pressed without giving them any aditional custom ids? I want to automate the process.

to make it a bit more clear:
- I would have Old password, New Password and Retype Password fields.
- I would like to call for each button the toggleField function to act on the input type password field (that precedes them) individually
- If I create additional password fields I would automatically apply the function to them as well

Comment: You could send in a string as a variable, so onclick="toggleFieldI(true, 'old'), then in your JS, toggleField(bool, type), then you check for the type (the string you sent), if (type === 'old') then do this, if (type === 'new') do other stuff. The string can be anything you want, there are no limits to the types of functions you can create when you pass in arguments.

Comment: That is still too specific and I would have to add each type manually in the function every time I create a new input field. I want the function to act as a template regardless of what is in the input field's values or classes.

Comment: I would like something like this: https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-show-password where the function is controlled via a standard parameter: <input id="password" class="form-control" type="password" data-toggle="password">